# Don't understand the potential leak

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I was using the Analyze function in xcode, and I've fixed everything except this one.

I'm wondering what this exactly means of a "potential leak of an object allocated", and it refers to these lines.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.type_prod = [[ProductType alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductType" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSString *prodtitle = [product objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    type_prod.prodtitle = prodtitle;

 etc etc.
```

At the end of this void I say:

```
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:type_prod animated:YES];
[type_prod release];
```

So why does it say there is a potential leak if I release it at the end?

Comment: [ProductType alloc] = 1 retain count
self.type_prod + 1
[type_prod release] - 1

Comment: I understand my retain count is 1 because I alloc, but because I release it, it will be 1-1=0 (at least that's what I thought). But it turns out that self.type_prod increases its retain count +1?

Comment: I guess your retain count is 2 coz of self.type_prod wich is most likely uses retain.

Comment: I realize I lack knowledge about the use of "self" and what it exactly is. I used it here, but I'm not sure why I said self.type_prod instead of type_prod.. could someone give me references to understand this concept?

Comment: self.type_prod = {some value} equals to [self setType_prod:{some value}]. In your code there shoud be '@property', '@syntesize'. They generate getter and setter for a property. if you use '@property' (retain)... you will get additional retain count from self.type_prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume type_prod is a retained property. You need to release it in the dealloc method with `self.type_prod = nil`.

Also make sure the release at the end is executed in all cases. It is safer to autorelease it right away:

```
self.type_prod = [[[ProductType alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductType" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
```

Comment: I put in the autorelease like you said, and at the end of the void I changed [type_prod release]; to self.type_prod = nil. Because I have an autorelease, I assume I don't need to have a release before self.type_prod = nil, right? Is it necessary to have [type_prod release]; in the -(void)dealloc? It's hard for me to understand the concept of self.

Comment: If you have the autorelease like i said in my answer you must NOT release the ivar again in the method. The release in dealloc with self.type_prod = nil in dealloc is necessary. This is identical to [self setType_prod:nil].